# jQuery inArray only looking at first value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#client').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#client').val() != $('.recent_client').attr('id')) {
        $('.recent_client').removeClass('recent_client_active').addClass('recent_client_inactive');
    }
    else if (jQuery.inArray(parseInt($('#client').val()), client_ids)) {
        alert('IN ARRAY');
    }
});
```

**My HTML**

```
<p><input type="text" name="client" id="client" placeholder="Click here and start typing your client name..."></p>

<div id="recent_clients">
<p><a href="#" class="recent_client recent_client_inactive" id="Client Name 1">Client Name 1</a><a href="#" class="recent_client recent_client_inactive" id="Client Name 2">Client Name 2</a><a href="#" class="recent_client recent_client_inactive" id="Client Name 3">Client Name 3</a><a href="#" class="recent_client recent_client_inactive" id="Client Name 4">Client Name 4</a><a href="#" class="recent_client recent_client_inactive" id="Client Name 5">Client Name 5</a><a href="#" class="recent_client recent_client_inactive" id="Client Name 6">Client Name 6</a></p>
</div>
```

I have an array that contains the id values of each a in my #recent_clients div. Simple stuff. I also have an input box. If you type out the full name of one of the recent clients, I want that client name to highlight. So I assumed jQuery.inArray would help out with this, but it doesn't work. If I type out the first value of the array ("Client Name 1"), I get the alert. However, if I type any other client name following ("Client Name 2" for example), nothing happens.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the missing closing brace in the keyup code block a copy/paste error or is that also in the actual code?

Comment: I updated my code to include the actual .keyup function I have as well as the HTML. When I use jQuery.each to return the data of the array, it does display all 6 clients I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since inArray() works like indexOf, you should test for the result being > -1

**Updated**

```
    var client_ids = ['Client Name 1', 'Client Name 2', 'Client Name 3', 'Client Name 4', 'Client Name 5'];
$('#client').keyup(function() {
    if (jQuery.inArray($('#client').val(), client_ids) > -1) 
        $('#client').css('background-color','#00cc00');
    else
       $('#client').css('background-color','#cc0000');
});
```

Comment: I have tried that before, but then it doesn't alert me at all. So without '> -1', I at least get the first key/value pair, therefore I get my alert. With '> -1', I get nothing.

Comment: @dallen - This suggestion is correct, but you need to get rid of the `parseInt` since your id's are not integers.

Comment: @Chris I have done that as well, and I still only get the first key/value pair of the array returned.

Comment: Okay I found the problem. My first part of the if statement, "if ($('#client').val() != $('.recent_client').attr('id')) {" was messing with it. With it removed, it works just fine now.